# Default tool window settings in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

I'm customizing the Project tool window settings.

It works fine until I change the current project. In fact, these settings appear to be project-specific, and they reset when I create a new project.

So, how do I change these settings for all projects? I cannot find the default settings for the context menu of the Project tool window.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to make these settings global. There have been several questions about this on SO. I think there is even an issue on Jetbrains' YouTrack to make these settings global, though I can't find it right now.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt But IDEA has to load them from somewhere the first time. Would it be possible to edit the file where they are stored, or are they stored directly in code?

Comment: That's true. The settings for project are stored in workspace.xml and look like this: `<hideEmptyPackages /> <abbreviatePackageNames /> ...`. You might try to grep IntelliJ community source code for these names. It might give you a clue. I haven't  personally tried looking for it that deeply :)

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I [searched the GitHub repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/search?q=hideEmptyPackages) and I can only find [something related to Maven](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/210e0ed138627926e10094bb9c76026319cec178/plugins/maven/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/idea/maven/importing/configurers/MavenIdeaPluginConfigurer.java). That's strange. I don't understand what an `Element` is, can you help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with IntelliJ codebase, but the defaults for project view seem to be hardcoded in [`ProjectViewImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/61a520d16f7a5f1f424be0e98c705d86d78bd5aa/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/projectView/impl/ProjectViewImpl.java#L119). Not sure if you can easily change them

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt & Francesco Unless I'm missing something, most of them are *saveable* by using the [`Window` -> `Store current layout as default`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#manage) menu. So far (haven't had the need to tweak that many of them anyway) I only found that the `Maven` -> `Group modules` does not get preserved...

Comment: @Morfic I've already tried that option; it doesn't. It doesn't even save the tool window's size.